# Is there a way to control which Apple Pay is chosen when I pay from macOS?

Tags: macos, touch-id, apple-pay

When I choose to pay for something in macOS using Apple Pay (e.g., from Safari or the App Store) from Mac hardware that doesn't have a touchID hardware itself, I'm sometimes offers my iPhone and sometimes my Apple Watch. However, I don't see any pattern in which device is offered, and often the least convenient device is selected.

Is there a way to control which device is chosen for paying with Apple Pay, or to select or change to a different watchOS/iOS device?